# Save csv files using filenames in a map function loop

Tags: r, map-function

I am looping a number of csv files in a folder using the map function. I want to save the results of the loop using a sliced version of the name of the csv. But I am getting an error when attempting to save the results to csv. Here is my code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(dismo)

file_paths <- fs::dir_ls("loop/")

file_paths %>%
  map(function (path){
    all_data <- read_csv(path, show_col_types = FALSE)
    name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_paths))
    print(name)
    t_max <- all_data[,c(2)]
    t_min <- all_data[, c(3)]
    rain_fall <- all_data[,c(4)]
    res <- data.frame(biovars(t_max, t_min, rain_fall))
    myfile = sprintf("%s_bio.csv", name)
    write_csv(res, file=myfile, col_names = TRUE)
  })
```

Error:

```
Error in if (is_url(path)) { : the condition has length > 1
```

Comment: If you have errors then please include the literal error, don't make us guess. My guess: replace `tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_paths))` with `tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(path))`.

Comment: @r2evans, I have updated the question to include the error. How do I vote for your answer? Because it has actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the full vector of `full_paths` inside your `map`, you should be using just the singular `path`:

```r
file_paths %>%
  map(function (path){
    all_data <- read_csv(path, show_col_types = FALSE)
    name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(path))
    print(name)
    t_max <- all_data[,c(2)]
    t_min <- all_data[, c(3)]
    rain_fall <- all_data[,c(4)]
    res <- data.frame(biovars(t_max, t_min, rain_fall))
    myfile = sprintf("%s_bio.csv", name)
    write_csv(res, file=myfile, col_names = TRUE)
  })
```